# how to find ids of all enabled input fields in a perticular form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

i have a form that has many input fields. some fields of them are disabled and some are enabled. so i want to know that how to find the Ids of all enabled input fields and validate them simultenaously. could you help me. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thake a look on [`:enabled`](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) selector documentation. That should help.

You should do something like this:

```
$(':enabled').each(function(index) {
    alert(index);
});
```